# Problems came up in the following areas during loading : Excel Name

Tags: excel, notepad++, office-interop

So I am building a report in Progress ABL to open in Excel afterwards. Nothing complicated, simple `< TABLE>` with each `< TR>` having 7 `< TD>` data column. Then I open excel using `interop` and I paste the table on a worksheet of a new workbook.

When building this specific report, I get this error on the screen (see title and picture). The report should open in our ERP viewer but the error message appears then it opens in Excel which shouldn't be the case.

[image: Description]

**Translation :Problems came up in the following areas during loading : Excel Name**

I searched for this specific problem but only have found for "Table" or "AutoSort".

I know there is a tag on the file when I open it in `Notepad++` that says ExcelName but I don't know what is the problem.
Is there a list of those error somewhere that could light me up ?

Comment: It will help if you translate the error message shown in the screenshot.

Comment: "Problems came up in the following areas during loading : Excel Name"

As I wrote, it is both in the picture and the title. I had to search a bit for that translated message because it is certainly not an even translation from French.